# centos 6.7 ArcGIS for Server 10.3.1: publishingtools will not start?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, centos

We're experimenting with ArcGIS for Server (10.3.1) on CentOS (6.7) and I've run into a wall; specifically this:

> Service failed to start 
>   System.PublishingTools.GPServer: 
>   LOCALHOST 
>   Could not create object 'esriGeoprocessing.GPServer'.

My analyst claims the sample service, "SampleWorldCities", worked previously, that he could connect to it AND preview the Geography in ArcCatalog. Unfortunately, I'm not *entirely* convinced that is true ..so consider that a possible red herring.

However the sample server *HAS* always been visible, of that I am certain..

Meanwhile, I've been going through the motions of adding PostGRESql, and today my analyst says the sample service is unavailable to him.

I suggested we try publishing a new service with a shapefile as an experiment, but ArcServer fails immediately. Anyway it seems System > PublishingTools is stopped and will not start.

Things I've tried:

- stopping/restarting ArcGIS Server, e.g. `service arcgisserver [stop|start]`
- rebooting the system entirely, e.g. `reboot`
- logs have been vague and no help ..particularly when googling errors with "CentOS" among my search terms
- stopping iptables *entirely*, just in case [the documentation misled me](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/59690#comment-284095) and I needed to open additional ports, e.g.
  `service iptables stop`
  `service ip6tables stop`
- double-checking the ArcServer Manager > System > PublishingTools > Edit Service > Pooling:
  ..*curiously*, `maximum instances` *shows* 0 in the dashboard, even though `minimum instances` is set to 1 and `maximum instances` is set to 2. I tried changing the max to 3, saving, then restarting it, and it remained at 0 in the dashboard. I thought this was odd ..but perhaps residual of it failing to start in the first place.
- double-checking ArcServer Manager > System > PublishingTools > Edit Service Security:
  Like iptables, I tried to side-step issues here by setting this to `Public, available to everyone`, then restarting it. Same.

Have I overlooked an obvious requirement necessary to enabling the PublishingTools.GPServer service? Alternatively, is there another troubleshooting step I might try to dig a little deeper?

Comment: I've had services stop and immediately fail to start due to the license expiring on the server. The logs in Server Manager were surprisingly helpful, but I think the log level had to be adjusted in the log settings to see the error. It might help to paste any errors you are getting in your question.

Comment: Sometimes a service gets corrupted.  Sometimes a security patch changes a required library in a certain way.  Technically, CentOS is not supported, or it's only supported if the issue can be reproduced on RedHat.  I've had to move projects off CentOS 6 to RedHat 6 because of compatibility issues.  I suggest you uninstall Server and reinstall.  If the problem persists, contact Tech Support.